# How can I access Legend's parameters: LegendLines (thickness, color, dashed) and LegendLables (FontSize, FontFamily FontColor)

Tags: legending

How can I access the features of LegendLines (thickness, color, dashed) and LegendLables (Fontsize, FontFamily, FontColor) in the same legend column?

I manage to change either of them, but not both together.

In this example I changed the parameters of LegendLables (PlotLegends) but I do not know how to make the LegendLines thicker:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Sin[Cos[3 x]]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.015]], Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]], Directive[Green, Thickness[0.015], Dashed]}, 
PlotLegends -> {Style["Sin(x)", Blue, Bold, 21, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Style["Cos(x)", Red, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic], Style["SinCos(3x)", Green, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Courier"]}]
```

[image]

In this example I changed the parameters of LegendLines but I do not know how to color the LegendLables with different colors and their types.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Sin[Cos[3 x]]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.015]], Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]], Directive[Green, Thickness[0.015], Dashed]},  
PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.4]], Directive[Red, Thickness[0.4]], Directive[Green, Thickness[0.4], Dashed]}, {"Sin(x)", "Cos(x)", "SinCos(3x)"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Does `PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[{Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.4]], 
    Directive[Red, Thickness[0.4]], 
    Directive[Green, Thickness[0.4], Dashed]}, {Style["Sin(x)", Blue, 
     Thick, Bold, 21, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
    Style["Cos(x)", Red, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic], 
    Style["SinCos(3x)", Green, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Courier"]}]]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr, Thanks!!! it gives me what I need. The question is answered!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Sin[Cos[3 x]]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.015]], 
   Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]], Directive[Green, Thickness[0.015], Dashed]}, 
 PlotLegends ->  LineLegend[{Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.4]], 
    Directive[Red, Thickness[0.4]], Directive[Green, Thickness[0.4], Dashed]}, 
   {Style["Sin(x)", Blue, Thick, Bold, 21, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
    Style["Cos(x)", Red, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic], 
    Style["SinCos(3x)", Green, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Courier"]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am using your method. How do I change the length of the lines in LineLegend? Does your post need updating; are there more features in more recent versions? Thanks

Comment: @Hugh, you can add the option `LegendMarkerSize -> 30` to `LineLegend`.

Comment: Thanks this works nicely. I have the legend items at the bottom of my plot `Placed[...,Below]` and now they have wrapped to more than one line. How do I prevent this?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Hugh, add the option `LegendLayout ->{"Row", 1}` to `LineLegend`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Where can I find all these options?  I don't want to keep asking you!

Comment: @Hugh, see [LineLegend >> Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html)

Comment: Very helpful but usages like `LegendLayout-> {"Row",1}` is  not so obvious to me. Thanks I will work at this I need to study this more.